# Rotate triangle in openGL android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I did a simple app based on the sample of getting started at developer.android.com. It was working fine, but I changed the rotation logic and now it doesn't show the triangle. I'm not sure I understood the matrix stuff, so I would like if someone could check my code.
This is the SurfaceView method I think may have a problem:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){
    float x = e.getX();
    float y = e.getY();

    switch(e.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        float rotateX = 0.0f;
        float rotateY = 0.0f;
        float rotateZ = 0.0f;

        //na coluna da esquerda, rotação no eixo Z
        if(x < getWidth() / 3){
            rotateZ = (y - previousY);
        }
        //na coluna do meio, rotação no eixo X
        if(getWidth()/3 < x && x < 2*getWidth()/3){
            rotateX = (y - previousY);
        }
        //na coluna da direita, rotação no eixo Z invertido
        if(x > getWidth() / 3){
            rotateZ = - (y - previousY);
        }

        //na linha superior, rotação no eixo Z
        if(y < getHeight() / 3){
            rotateZ = (x - previousX);
        }
        //na linha do meio, rotação no eixo Y
        if(getHeight()/3 < y && y < 2*getHeight()/3){
            rotateY = (x - previousY);
        }
        //na linha inferior, rotação no eixo Z invertido
        if(y > 2*getHeight() / 3){
            rotateZ = - (x - previousX);
        }

        mRenderer.setAngulo(mRenderer.getAnguloX() + (rotateX) * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR,
                            mRenderer.getAnguloY() + (rotateY) * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR,
                            mRenderer.getAnguloZ() + (rotateZ) * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR);
        requestRender();

    }
    previousX = x;
    previousY = y;
    return true;
}
```

This is the renderer method:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

    //desenha o fundo
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //define a posição da camera
    //Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -5f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    //cria uma matrix para a rotação de cada angulo
    Matrix.setRotateM(xRotationMatrix, 0, anguloX, 1, 0, 0);
    Matrix.setRotateM(yRotationMatrix, 0, anguloY, 0, 1, 0);
    Matrix.setRotateM(zRotationMatrix, 0, anguloZ, 0, 0, 1);

    float[] mMatrix = new float[16];
    //aplica todas as rotações na matrix scratch
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMatrix, 0, xRotationMatrix, 0, mMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMatrix, 0, yRotationMatrix, 0, mMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMatrix, 0, zRotationMatrix, 0, mMatrix, 0);

    // Calcula a view e depois a projeção
    Matrix.multiplyMM(resultingMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(resultingMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, resultingMatrix, 0);

    // Draw shape
    triangulo.draw(resultingMatrix);
}
```

The Triangulo class must be right because I didn't changed it since the last time the app was working.

Comment: For problems like this, you can often approach them by going back to the code that works, then changing small pieces.  When it stops working, you only have to examine that one small change.

Comment: Actually I have the code that works, but it is just to different that I can't add just a part of the new code. I think I edited it too much at once

Answer (score 0):

Well, i analysed your code thoroughly and there does not seem to be any problem in it.

But, i guess the problem is this :

When you call

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -5f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

You are setting the camera at Z = -5 and looking towards origin i.e towards the +ve Z direction.

(I guess initially the vertices of the triangle must be in XY plane and hence the triangle is visible.)

Then when you call

```
Matrix.setRotateM(zRotationMatrix, 0, anguloZ, 0, 0, 1);
```

It rotates the triangle about Z axis which is fine.

But then you call

```
Matrix.setRotateM(xRotationMatrix, 0, anguloX, 1, 0, 0);
Matrix.setRotateM(yRotationMatrix, 0, anguloY, 0, 1, 0);
```

Here you are rotating the triangle about X and Y axis and since triangles have no thickness,
It becomes invisible.

Possible fixes :

1) Remove the rotations about X and Y axis and check if it works.

```
                  OR
```

2) Put a cube instead of triangle and see if it works.

```
                  OR
```

3) If neither works, give me the full code.I will debug and run it.

Best of Luck